# Changing the SharePoint search results page. Show custom column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The search on my SharePoint site is working well for us. But there is a slight snag.
One of my columns in the main doc library is called "Display Name". 
This can sometimes differ with what the actual file name is.
When searching, the results show the filename and then some text from the file.
So a file can return 2020AssmtNav200 when it should just show "Assessment Navigation for site 200".

Is it possible to change this so it shows the "Display Name" field instead of the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it required some planning. The custom column needs to be  a Site Column, not just a column that was created on the fly in the library.

You can configure Search to include custom site columns by pointing a Mapped Property to the crawled property of that site column.

It's all a bit too much to explain in detail in an answer here. Read up about how to configure SharePoint Server search. You did not specify your SharePoint version. Things are different depending on that.

Comment: Using SharePoint 2016. I've made the site column and mapped the property.
I've also made copies of the Item_default.html layout and even added the ManagedPropertyMapping to that file. Beyond that however, I'm stumped. I'm feeling my way through here.

Comment: If you map the crawled property to the Mapped Property for Title, it should show up in the Search results without any further manipulation. Of course you need to do a full crawl after configuring mapped properties.